# Want to remove the listview adapter item completely?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to remove all items at a time from my listView adapter. For that I am using m_adapter.clear() function. But after I m going out from the app, and when I again come back to it the listview again regenerated as usual. I need to clear them permanently,so that again I can add new views to it. Can any body suggest me anything on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are not clearing the container of your `data` by which you are populating the `ListView`. You have to clear the `Array` or `ArrayList` whatever container you are using to populate the `ListView`.